# How do you stream text to an IRC Channel

Tags: c#, irc

does anyone know how you go about streaming text to a IRC server?

I have a game server, and i'd like to stream the chat to IRC.  I can get the chat as a string within a C# program..

Anyone know how to do this?  Or a good resource to look at?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Write an IRC bot.

[Use an existing IRC library](http://smartirc4net.meebey.net/jaws/) or use the [RFC describing the IRC protocol](http://irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/rfc.html) to develop your own, to write an IRC bot that will be able to send text to the channel.